# Sign(+/-) error in byte in Java byte setting operations

Tags: java, c++, char, byte

I am declearing in Java

```
public byte[] orbits = new byte[38];
```

Now if I am doing

```
orbits[24] = (byte)0xFF;
```

orbits[24] should get populated by 11111111 i.e FF(in hexadecimal) but instead its getting populated with -1.

This operation in C++ working perfectly

```
char orbits[38]
orbits[24] = (char)0xFF;
```

How to replicate the similar situation in Java using byte?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it just happens that -1 is 0xFF. Everything is correct. `byte` stores values from -128 to 127 using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

In Java there are no unsigned types. If you want to use bit patterns, then use byte. 0xFF and -1 are the same thing in this situation. If you want to use numbers, that is, 0xFF is actually 255 and not -1, then you need to use a bigger type, like short.

Comment: SO are you telling that if we compare them bit by bit then it will be equal in Java by lets say a for loop.